# Count and filter on the basis of third column in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Like I have a question

```
Col1        Col2 Col3
45321_320    A    Y
45321_320    A    N
76453-10     A    Y
45638_80     A    Y
```

So we need to count the no of rows that have same col1 for example the first two rows should be considered as count=2 and rest as count=1 and after that count=2 or more that records need to filtered out on the basis of Col3=Y, so how we can do that in informatica

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkxnG.png

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is little tricky. Pls follow below steps.

1. Sort the data base on col1.
2. Use agg to aggregate. Create a new col called count_col1.
   create another col, cnt_col3_y = count(*, col3=y)
3. Join agg output with sorter output based on col1.
4. Put a filter. Logic should be

```
iif( count_col1>1 and cnt_col3>0, false, true)
```

5. Link output of filter to target.

This will generate output like below.

```
Col1        Col2 Col3
76453-10     A    Y
45638_80     A    Y
```

If you want different output let me know.